# SQL left join with where over three tables

Tags: sql

I need Help with a SQL statement :-(

Lets say have three Tables:

```
Table1
id / vorname / user

Table2
id / groupename / user / level

Table 3
id /groupename / description
```

At the moment my SQL looks like this:

```
select table1.vorname, table2.groupename, table2.user, table2.level from table2 left join table1 on table2.user = table1.user;
```

So i get the all Data (users) auf Table 2 with the right uservorname of Table 1.

And now i stuck ...

I have the id from Table 3 and need to limit the recordset to only those groupes.

The key in this case is the groupename so i have to get the groupename from Table3 where the id ist the same that i have and compare the groupename with the groupename from Table2 to limit the records only to this groupe ...

```
Table2.groupename = Table3.groupename
```

But i dont know how to solve it.

THANK YOU !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something old-school like

```
select table1.vorname, table2.groupename, table2.user, table2.level 
from table1, table2, table3 
where table2.user = table1.user 
and table2.groupename = table3.groupename
and table3.id = '[my id]'
```

Using Joins is possibly more efficient, and possibly makes the intent clearer.

```
select table1.vorname, table2.groupename, table2.user, table2.level 
from table1
inner join table2 on table2.user = table1.user
inner join  table3 on table2.groupename = table3.groupename
where table3.id = '[my id]'
```

Comment: Omg so simple ... when you know it ... :-) THANK YOU!

Answer (score 1):

```
select     table1.vorname, 
           table2.groupename, 
           table2.user, 
           table2.level 
from       table2 
inner join table3 on table2.groupname = table3.groupname
left join  table1 on table2.user = table1.user
```